# Adding variable to a number in jquery id name

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
loopVar=1;
alert('#imgAvatar'+parseInt(loopVar)+1);
```

gives me #imgAvatar**11**

While

`alert(parseInt(loopVar)+1);`

gives me 2

How can I get #imgAvatar**2** ?

Comment: Might be you want this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346771/adding-variable-to-a-number-in-jquery-id-name/29346924#29346924

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add parenthesis `()` for priority to evaluate add `loopVar` first. If your variable contains numeric value then do not need to apply `parseInt` function.

```
loopVar = "1";
alert('#imgAvatar'+(parseInt(loopVar)+1));
```

OR

```
loopVar = 1;
alert('#imgAvatar'+ (loopVar+1) );
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Loqznohg/)**

Answer (score 5):

Your loopVar is already an integer (notice you haven't put it in quotes, so it is integer). No need to do parseInt.

Use it:

```
loopVar=1;
alert('#imgAvatar'+(loopVar+1));
```

**FIDDLE**:
http://jsfiddle.net/15bucsy5/

Comment: Guys I Apologize, my loopVar was char probably.

Comment: So then, you can use parseInt on loopVar.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're adding to the string `#imgAvatar` so the numbers will be converted to strings as well, and it's really read as `"#imgAvatar" + "1" + "1"`.

Use parentheses to create a block where the numbers can be added up before they are added to the string

```
var loopVar = 1;
alert( '#imgAvatar' + ( (+loopVar) + 1 ) );
```

Whenever the addition operator is used with a string, all other values will be converted to strings as well

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rLr74yop/1/)

Comment: sorry but not working for me. Only Sadikhasan version worked fine.

Comment: @David - It's exactly the same as the rest, but who cares !

Comment: Guys I Apologize, my loopVar was char probably.

Answer (score 2):

Thats the trouble:

```
"foo" + 1 + 1 == "foo1"+1 == "foo11";
```

Thats the answer

```
alert( '#imgAvatar' + ( parseInt(loopVar) + 1) ) );
```

P.S. jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/emtLfv9r/

If not worknig - show to us your html.

Comment: sorry but not working for me. Only Sadikhasan version worked fine.

Comment: it because i added jQuery selector, cos i think, that u wanna select that. nvm, glad for u

Comment: Guys I Apologize, my loopVar was char probably.

Comment: oh, so in that way - right ans is ('#imgAvatar' + ( parseInt(loopVar)+1) )